# Flexbox mixed full and half width layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 7 items in a container. How can I make the first 3 be full width and the next 7 be 50% width?

I also need element that are in the same row visually to have the same height.

I can use flexbox for this if necessary. In this demo the container has a fixed width but in reality its a responsive layout so the width varies.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJoPwK

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.item-1 {
  background: blue;
}
.item-2 {
  background: green;
}
.item-3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.item-4 {
  background: blue;
}
.item-5 {
  background: grey;
}
.item-6 {
  background: orange;
}
.item-7 {
  background: gold;
}
.item-4,
.item-5,
.item-6,
.item-7 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4 <br> wrap</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
</div>
```

This is the layout im trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the container to `flex-flow: row wrap;`

Set the first 3 flex items to `width: 100%;` and last 4 items to `width: 50%;`

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXovaR)**

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item-1 { background: blue; }
.item-2 { background: green; }
.item-3 { background: yellow; }
.item-4 { background: blue; }
.item-5 { background: grey; }
.item-6 { background: orange; }
.item-7 { background: gold; }
.item-1, .item-2, .item-3 { width: 100%; }
.item-4, .item-5, .item-6, .item-7 { width: 50%; }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4 <br> wrap</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `.item-4` and `item-5` create two sub elements `item-4-1`, `item-4-2`,

then `.item-4, .item-5{display: flex}` will do the job

Demo

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.item-1 {
  background: blue;
}
.item-2 {
  background: green;
}
.item-3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.item-4 {
  background: blue;
}
.item-5 {
  
}
.item-4, .item-5{
  display: flex
}
.item-4 .sub-item, .item-5 .sub-item{
  width: 50%;
}
.item-4 .item-4-2{
  background: grey;
}

.item-5-1 {
  background: orange;
}
.item-5-2 {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">
    <div class="sub-item item-4-1">4 <br> wrap</div>
    <div class="sub-item item-4-2">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-5">
    <div class="sub-item item-5-1">6</div>
    <div class="sub-item item-5-2">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```